# How i can get last posts and give each of them deferent style

Tags: php, sql

How i can get last posts sql

```
SELECT id,name,image FROM posts order by ID DESC LIMIT 5;
```

and get every string deferent style

like:

image from Column1 $row[0] biggest size

image from Column2.$row[0], Column3.$row[0] ... fixed size

Comment: Well that seems like a fairly simple process. You fetch the first row from and format as you want and then fetch the next 4 and do it differently. What do you need us for ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i use your code to fix it like that:

```
$query = "SELECT id,name,image FROM posts order by ID DESC LIMIT 5";
    $i = 0;
        while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            
    $i++;
        
                if ($i == 1) {
                   echo"$f[2] -large<br>";
                }else{
                    echo"$f[2] -small<br>";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The first row is 0 as rows always start from 0,1,2...

So what i did here, while going through fetched rows, i have used an if else statement, where i check if the row is equal to 0 then it means its the first row, else you have other rows 1,2,3... etc.

```
 $query = "SELECT id,name,image FROM posts order by ID DESC LIMIT 5";
        
    while ($f = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        
            $row = 0;
            if ($row == 0) {
                //your first post here
    
                $row++;
            }else{
                // your other posts 
            }
        }
```

Comment: **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly is this a good answer, just updated.

Comment: Better, but you are still encouragig the DIFM's

Comment: @RiggsFolly Whats DIFM's ?

Comment: i think it not resolve my qustion

Comment: @Ali edit your question put your whole code there.

Comment: DIFM = "Do It For Me"